# char-to-char substituion with sed

Tags: sed

I am trying to make a monoalphabetic substitution decoder in bash: I have a set of characters that form an alternative alphabet like

```
real alphabet -> ABCDE ...
my alphabet   -> DGHJK ...
```

I want sed (or another tool, but I think sed can handle it) to replace "A" with "D", "B" with "G" and so on. Is it possible, without using the "-e" argument in sed (and typing all the alphabet) to perform such a substitution?

Answer (score 5):

Try:

```
$ echo ABCDBAD | sed 'y/ABCD/DEFG/'
DEFGEDG
```

`y/string1/string2/` causes `sed` replace all occurrences of characters in `string1` with the corresponding characters in `string2`.

Comment: Thanks! As usual, it works with files (in place) as `sed -i 'y/ABCD/DEFG/' 'path/to/file'`.

Comment: @Sadi: You need GNU sed for `-i` without suffix. In BSD sed, you need `-i ''`

Answer (score 5):

Instead of `sed`, use `tr`:

```
tr 'A-Z' 'DGHJK...' < input
```